# QML ListView section works in 6.5.1 but not in 5.15.2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The following code works as expected in 6.5.1 but not in 5.15.2

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: fakeModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: modelData.name
        }
        section.property: "blockName"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: Text {
            text: section
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    property var fakeModel: [{
            "blockName": "ABC",
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }, {
            "blockName": "ABC",
            "name": "Front Raises"
        }, {
            "blockName": "ZXC",
            "name": "Band Tall "
        }, {
            "blockName": "ZXC",
            "name": "Overhead"
        }]
}
```

I'm using EndeavourOS Linux 6.1.55-1-lts

in 5.15.2:

[image: in 5.15.2]

in 6.5.2:

[image: in 6.5.2]

Does anyone know if there is any work around for making the listview sections work with qt5?

Thanks

Comment: if I use a ListModel instead of a JSON model, it works on 5.15.2

Comment: Sounds like a bug that was fixed in Qt6 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in the comments, for Qt5.15.x use `ListModel`. If you wish to keep your declarative array, you can read and convert it to populate your `ListModel`, e.g.

```
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            function load(arr) { clear(); arr.forEach(e => append(e)) }
            Component.onCompleted: load(fakeModel)
        }
        delegate: Text {
            text: name
        }
        section.property: "blockName"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: Text {
            text: section
            color: "red"
        }
    }
    
    property var fakeModel: [{
            "blockName": "ABC",
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }, {
            "blockName": "ABC",
            "name": "Front Raises"
        }, {
            "blockName": "ZXC",
            "name": "Band Tall "
        }, {
            "blockName": "ZXC",
            "name": "Overhead"
        }]
```